# For a bridge/beam, how will the Young's modulus affect the susceptibility of it buckling?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, statics

I originally thought that a higher Young's modulus would increase susceptibility, but now I'm thinking it might be independent.

Comment: Do you mean buckling due to lateral torsion and that sort of thing?

Comment: Look at the formulas for Euler buckling in any textbook. They answer your question.

Comment: do you mean all else fixed?  Or did the designer take advantage of the higher stiffness and utilize thinner beams?  Susceptibility is a pretty vague term by the way.

Answer (score 1):

A column is typically modeled using the Euler's formula.  The idea is that as a column is compressed, the column will displace via compressing, or it can maintain its original length by deflecting into an arc.  This outward deflection is known as buckling. As a curved arc, the length between the two endpoints may have a shorter distance, as the shortest path between two points is a straight line.  However, this deflection will cause the overall length of the beam to remain the same.  A column made with material of a higher modulus of elasticity will have less deformation under a given stress, so overall it should handle more load before buckling.

We can verify this concept by looking at the Euler's formula for buckling:

$$ F = \frac{n\pi EI}{L^2}$$

Where E is the Young's modulus, I is the moment of Inertia, and L is the effective length (n is a constant based on the end conditions).  Reviewing the force required, we can see that two given beams of the same cross section and the same length, but with different modulus of elasticity, the stiffer beam can handle more force before buckling is onset.

Thus a beam with a higher modulus of elasticity will have a higher factor of safety against buckling than an identically designed beam with a lower modulus of elasticity.  An engineer would therefore state that a stiffer beam is less susceptible to buckling.

Comment: I don't think you meant to use "deflect" there.  "Deform" is a more appropriate term.  When a column buckles in vertical compression it deflects laterally.  If the compression doesn't cause buckling, it wont cause deflection; the deflection is the column losing it's straightness.

Comment: @JMac - The column will deflect vertically, that's Hooke's Law (obviously).  But the lateral buckling is clearly deformation rather than deflection.

Comment: Hookes law is that it will _deform_ vertically.  Deflection is caused by bending.  You're mixing it up.  Lateral buckling is deflection; the column bends (or deflects) so that elements are no longer lined up in the same orientation.  I think you're thinking of loaded beams, where the load generates a moment that causes deflection.  In an axially loaded member, that doesn't happen unless the load buckles.  Under normal circumstances there is only linear deformation.

Comment: @JMac answer edited.  Let me know if this fits with what you were thinking.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that'll do it.